# Read -110V signal with Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors

I need an Arduino to recognize a falling edge of the pulse from +10 to -110 V. What is the best way of doing that?

My best idea for now is to use an NPN transistor and make something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5k8Lg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This way when I have a +10V on the input, the arduino pin is HIGH. Then the -110V pulse comes, the transistor closes and the pin is pulled to the ground. The resistors values are arbitrary 
for now. My questions to you electronics gurus are: 
1) will this work? 
2) is there a better way to accomplish what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the -110V from?

Comment: -110 V is a voltage applied to an electrode in an ion optics system. It comes from a DC power supply. I need to trigger an external event off that signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your transistor will not particularly like -110V on its base. Nor is your transistor still a switching device, it's better not to have an emitter resistance if you want a sharp and fast response, since it'll want to be an emitter follower rather than a switcher.

You should make a few small adaptations, though your initial thought is a reasonable one.

First you will want to protect the transistor from noticing much, if anything, from the negative voltage by adding a diode to the input path:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHH6gh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If it's +10V, the resistor R2 and D1 will conduct current into R1 and Q1's base, this will be the case until the signal falls below an approximate +2V. Around 0V input the diode D1 will start blocking, and all the way down to -110V it'll keep blocking, as long as its breakdown is more than the most negative. The schematic shows 150V+ to indicate that 150V would be a good minimum to set for a safety margin.

The reverse leak of the diode will be mostly handled by R1, so the base can be assumed to be at or very close to ground, 0V.

Now, you might put the resistor back in the emitter path to keep the signal positive, but the emitter follower will make your resistor choices on the input much more sensitive, so it's much easier to just use it as a switcher:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frb47c.png)</sup>

In this way it will make a very nice and sharp flank at or around an input of 2V, so you'll also have a little margin for noise on the input, in case you need it.

Of course your output is now inverted, when the input is high, the output will be low, but in the uC you can also look for a flank upwards, in stead of downwards. On Atmels any pin you can use to look for a flank down, can also look for a flank up with a slightly different configuration, for how to do that with Arduino you'll have to look at those interfaces, I don't know Arduino specifically. But all Arduinos use an Atmel chip.

If you do it in software yourself by comparing values, you can just turn your reaction around.

If you still want a 1:1 response, you can add another transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fneU3m.png)</sup>

When Q1 turns on, it pulls the base of the PNP, Q2, low and that transistor will turn on, conducting into the R5, making the output go to the supply voltage. If Q1 is off, Q2's base will be pulled high by R4, and it'll turn off, allowing R5 to pull the output low again.

Comment: Yes, I doing the software part myself, and Arduino has no problems handling the inverted response. Adding a diode sounds like a very good idea, thank you, and also huge thanks for the very helpful comments!

Comment: @AndreyDyachenko No problem at all. We're all here to help, after all. I try to make a complete answer in all cases, you never know the level of knowledge from the average question, or from the people searching later, so better to say too much than too little.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using a 2N3904 with the circuit shown, you will probably blow out the transistor. The transistor can handle 6V of emitter-base voltage, when you have a -110V signal in, your EB voltage will be far more than that. However, if you had a transistor that could handle these voltages, then the circuit should work the way you want it to.

I wouldn't recommend using this circuit regardless, however. -110V is pretty high (is this from the mains?), and if something went wrong you could easily damage or destroy your arduino. Consider using an optocoupler to isolate the high voltage line from the arduino, it can be done in a circuit not too different from what you have already.